# Does the order of HashSet.Intersect() matter for performance? 

Tags: .net, algorithm, collections, intersection, hashset

I'm guessing it does NOT, but if someone could confirm.

If I try to intersect two sets:
A (1 million items)
B (1 item)

Does the framework always do A.Contains(B) once, instead of B.Contains(A) one million times?

This is assuming that's how intersects work beneath the hood, as opposite to some fancy algorithm I am not aware of.

**UPDATE:**

OK so for c# you should clearly do `B.InsersectWith(A)`, if B << A. `Intersect()` is defined on `IEnumerable` and would be a lot less efficient based on the answers below (and MSDN). So the order does matter if you use the best tool, which is `IntersectWith()`.

Comment: Update: OK so I forgot to mention this is a .NET question. Relax :-)

Comment: If you are looking for a single item why would you intersect?

Comment: yeah I asked which language is it. Didn't get the reply after 30 mins, then removed my comment. Because of the `algorithm` tag your question didn't make much sense.Look at the answers. Now it does.

Comment: Are you talking about `Enumerable<T>.Intersect` or `HashSet<T>.IntersectWith`?

Comment: Blam: Single item is an example to show the most extreme case of unbalance between sets. @CodesInChaos I was asking about Intersect but could easily use IntersectWith if its underlying algorithm is different.

Comment: I highly suspect the algorithm is different.  A HashsSet has hash buckets and knows uniqueness.  IntersetWith is only a HashSet or SortedSet  but you have the problem tagged as HashSet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation

If the collection represented by the other parameter is a HashSet collection with the same equality comparer as the current HashSet object, this method is an O(n) operation. Otherwise, this method is an O(n + m) operation, where n is Count and m is the number of elements in other.

[HashSet.IntersectWith Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb293080%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

And if you are looking for speed implement (override) GetHashCode if you can derive a meaningful Hash from your data. And override Equal. I do this for any class that will be in a collection.

[Object.GetHashCode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you are asking as a general question or for a specific language.

In Java, it will iterate over the second set and then over the first to see if it contains that element. So it will still iterate over both sets.

In c#, what the method does is to enumerate on the elements of the first set (A), then enumerate on the elements of the second set(B) and mark those that are common, afterwards it yields those elements in that order.

So, to answer your question, I would say that it does not. This is it has to go through every container

Answer (score 0):

The code is written to be for the general case. If you are a special case like that, you should implement custom logic that is efficient for your particular use case.

The Contains() method just iterates through the list until it finds a match, so the order would definately be important if thats what it was doing, but I believe the other answer is correct in terms of how it works, because that means iterating each item a maximum of one time, vs a "Contains" solution could iterate the entire "child" list for each element in the master list.

Actual solution = x+y iterations
Contains solution = x+(x*y) iterations

Comment: `Contains solution = x+(x*y)`. That's why in database this order is critical